# Prime number finder cannot find prime, stops after 7

Tags: c++, linux, primes

So I made a simple prime number finder for the numbers between 3 and 200. It has to use a boolean variable, just fyi. No errors occur. output is:

> The prime numbers between 3 and 200 are:
>   3
>   5
>   7

Why does it not keep going? I have drawn it out on paper time and again and cannot find my logic error.

In addition; I wrote this out by hand because I do not know how to get the contents of my file. It exists on a remote host which I do not have root access to. Is there a better way to copy the file?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count=0;
cout<<"The prime numbers between 3 and 200 are: "<<endl;

for (int i=3;i<=200;i++)
    {
     for (int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
           bool ptest=i%j;
           if (!ptest)
             {
               break;
             }
           else if (ptest)
             {
                count=count+1;
                if (count==(i-2))
                cout<<i<<endl;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: the line `for(int j = 2; ji; j++)` shouldn't even compile. We can't help you if you don't paste the actual code.

Comment: If you're editing the code with a GUI terminal, there should be some sort of copy functionality available, although it would be specific to the particular app (if you specify the app in question someone may be able to answer).

Comment: I changed the code to be my best guess at what the OP's intent was and for concision. I still can't figure out what the `count == (i - 2)` is about.

Comment: @msw me either... output I get is "The prime numbers between 3 and 200 are: 
10
12"

Comment: @polarysekt They're "nearly-prime", that is 11 ± 1. ;) The OP is pretty close to a working generator, and also pretty far. *sigh*

Comment: @msw sorry - I have rolled back your change. The original code, if "sdf" is removed and "ji" changed to "j < i", does actually output "3 5 7", as OP claimed. However your edited version outputs "10 12".

Comment: @msw he is counting `+1` for each number between `2` and `i-1` which is coprime to `i`. Iff `i` is prime then all of those are coprime, and there are `i-2` of them. (Of course, it would have been simpler to count how many numbers are *not* coprime, and break out of the `j` loop upon hitting `count == 1` ! ).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set `count` back to `0` after using it in the `j` loop. Move the line:

```
int count = 0;
```

to be inside the first `for` loop. Then your program works correctly (although as msw indicated, it is not the most efficient technique!)

Comment: I like this answer as you've worked directly with the original code with the fewest changes, understanding fully the OP's intentions. Your explanation comment on the original question was very helpful as well.

Comment: @polarysekt +1. OP did manage to convert their thoughts into an algorithm, and translate that algorithm from paper to code (except for forgetting to reset `count`), which is an important skill to have in programming.  Now that it works correctly I'm sure he/she will be able to get on with making improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

1. You don't need to consider any even numbers in your code.
2. You have some logic errors in your code. The value of `count` needs to be checked after the second `for` loop. `count` needs to be reset before the second `for` loop begins.
3. You can stop immediately after you find the number is not prime in the inner loop instead of continuing on. You can just use a flag `isPrime` instead of counting.

Here's a version of the code that works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "The prime numbers between 3 and 200 are: " <<endl;

   for (int i=3; i <= 200; i += 2) {
      bool isPrime = true;
      for (int j=3; j < i; j += 2) {
         if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
         }
      }

      if (isPrime)
      {
         cout << i << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop till j reach i, instead you can check if  `j < sqrt(i)` ,i.e.  write in the second for loop:  `for (int j=3; j*j<=i; j+=2)`